# Using if_else or case_when to conditionally filter a dataframe in two different ways

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, case

Minimal example - I have 9 responses from 3 subjects to a questionnaire with two questions:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 4)),
                 Q1 = sample(0:5, 9, replace=T),
                 Q2 = sample(1:7, 9, replace=T),
                 Days_Used = c(rep(10, 2), rep(5, 3), rep(4, 4))
)
```

Think of Days_Used as End_Date - Start_Date. I would like to filter the dataframe in one of two ways - by Days_Used or the number of times the questionnaire is filled (i.e. by the number of rows associated with a subject), depending on whether the variable `FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I tried the following:

```
FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED <- TRUE
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  if_else(FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED,
          filter(Days_Used >= 5),
          filter(n() >= 3))
```

but get an error message when I execute it

```
Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object.
```

I would like to obtain the following output:

1. When `FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED` is `TRUE`: the first 5 rows corresponding to subjects A and B
2. When `FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED` is `FALSE`: the last 7 rows corresponding to subjects B and C

What is the correct syntax for my conditional filter?

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 5):

You were in the right direction. Try using `if`/`else` since this is a scalar comparison.

```
library(dplyr)

FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED <- TRUE

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(if(FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED) Days_Used >= 5 else n() >= 3) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID       Q1    Q2 Days_Used
#  <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1 A         0     3        10
#2 A         3     1        10
#3 B         0     5         5
#4 B         1     5         5
#5 B         4     2         5
```

Comment: It's striking that there are no commas in the syntax. - just the presence of  `else` acts as a separator. Also, event though I don't need it right now, I'm curious: how would the syntax change it I was carrying out a vector comparison?

Comment: For vector comparison in general you can use `ifelse`/`if_else` etc. Although, what would be an example of vector comparison?

Comment: One example of a vector comparison would be the use of multiple comparisons in the filter, though I suppose that could be handled using | and &. A more difficult example is filtering based on a function of earlier values in the same column (with different columns being selected depending on the value of FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED. It seems to me that this would require a loop.

Comment: Yes, it actually depends on your actual use case. If you have another flag like `FILTER_BY_DAYS_USED`, yes it can be done with `&` or `|`.